# USB модем управление настройками

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток! Много перерыл информации, но внятного нечего не нашел. Необходимо программного выставлять вот эту настройку.[image: Настройка планшета как модема через usb подключение]
Нашел только то, что возможно реализовать через System.Settings или System.Global но непонятно как?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913645/android-enable-usb-tethering-programmatically-there-is-an-app-that-did-it-fo

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Прочитал я документацию, прикрыли эта лавочку уже давно, изменять эту настройку сторонние приложения не могут.

Comment: На зарутованном телефоне всё можно! А по сути, если совсем не гуглится ничего, то исходники системы открыты. Это вам не iOS какой-нибудь.